# django admin form does not work in inline

Tags: django, django-admin

This is my form

```
class LoginForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Login
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'password': PasswordInput(),
        }
```

This is my inline

```
class LoginInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Login
```

This is my admin

```
class AppAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'link_href')
    inlines = [LoginInline]

class LoginAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = LoginForm
```

When I try to add login from login page, the password is correctly applied

[image]

But not from the app page using inline

[image]

How can I fix this ? I thought of adding another form for `AppAdmin` but the password field does not exist in `App` model only in `Login` model and I would like to know if there is a way to reference it inside another form

Comment: You LoginForm is not used on your inline class

Comment: @Walucas You are right I didn't know you it exists. Thanks

Comment: Of course... Saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test, but this should do it

```
class LoginInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = LoginForm
    model = Login
```